# Typescript/React: Module has no exported member

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to export prop types from one view component to another container component and use them as state type definitions:

```
// ./Component.tsx
export type Props {
    someProp: string;
}

export const Component = (props: Props ) => {
    ...etc
}

// ./AnotherComponent.tsx
import { Component, Props as ComponentProps } from "./Component";

type Props = {}

type State = ComponentProps & {};

class AnotherComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State;
    ...etc
}
```

**However I am getting in console:**

```
Module '"./Component "' has no exported member 'Props'.
```

Any suggestions for how I should be going about this?

I have also tried using lookup types as per [this](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/10-typescript-pro-tips-patterns-with-or-without-react-5799488d6680) article, but no joy.

Comment: `Module '"./AnotherComponent "' has no exported member 'Props'.`
 but `Module "./Component" has exported member 'Props'.` cheers

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue for the missing member export was the fact that I had an intermediary index file which TypeScript doesn't seem to be able to use when exporting types:

```
// ./Component/index.tsx
export { Component, Props } from "./js/Component";
```

When I change the import to use an exact path to the file rather than trying to import it through the index file it picked it up:

```
// ./AnotherComponent/js/AnotherComponent.tsx
import { Props as ComponentProps} from "./Component/js/Component";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Basically extend the component Props, to include your desired import.

```
export interface IProps extends PropsOfYouChoiceThatYouImport {
 morePropsHere
}
```

Also do not include Props into State it is completly wrong IMO. Do something like this:

```
interface IProps extends YourDesiredProps {
  someProp: string | null;
  // etc
}

interface IState {
  something: boolean
  // etc
}

export class ComponentName extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  // Define you state, and props here. You need to initialize the correct IState 
  // and IProps above
}
```

As for the console error, I am not sure you can do that.Try create a folder called `Types` or `Interfaces`. Then export that one.

And import it as named or default export, whatever you wish, at both files. Since you want to reuse it. Tell me if it helps. I can look more into it, if you make a quick codeSandbox..

Basically what I suggest is put this into a separate file:

```
export type Props {
    someProp: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't resolve the error above. Also I am guessing the props can only extend one other set of props, if I need to include more than one set of props this would be unsuitable right?

Comment: You can extend mutiple ones. just comma seperate them. But be careful. Incompatibly types are a headache to solve. If you find yourself in that scenario, maybe your architecture is wrong. Let me look at the error again. Maybe I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Please check my answer again. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, according to https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet#class-components it says " you can export/import/extend these types/interfaces for reuse.", surely there is a way to reuse these types without having to separate into a different type definitions file?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the React typings (`node_modules/react/index.d.ts`) of `React.Component` the structure is the following:

```
class Component<P, S> {...}
```

where `P` equal props and `S` means state.
You should not mix props and state.

To fix your TypeScript error change `type` to `interface`:

```
export interface Props {
  someProp: string;
}
```

Comment: Changing it to interface doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: It is quite difficult to guess what is the issue therefore I suggest you reproduce your issue in `codesandbox.io` which is a great online coding tool for front-end.
Here is a [sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3138x65p0) you can fork which has Typescript and React.